# My device is not listed in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I have an LG P760. Until yesterday, I had an U8800Pro that was listed along with my P760 phone under my account. The U8800 is now the phone of my wife and is listed under her account correctly.
But, my phone is not listed. I have disabled the U8800 from my phones list but the LG is not shown again. 
I have installed at least 2 applications via Play app in the LG but still Google Play store says that I have no phone connected with my account!
I also tried to Sync my phone with Google from Setting-->Apps-->Sync

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, delete all your google accounts restart your phone better re-insert the sim card. Go to gmail create your account again then try opening play store. If it doesn't work sync again! :)